# How can i fix the issue with CrystalReport PrintToPrinter method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, printing, crystal-reports

I have set up my iis server on windows 10 and i have deployed a mvc-5 web application on it every thing is working fine except the Crystal Reports PrintToPrinter ,when i try to call this method nothing prints and web app does nothing and just hangs there .but when i developed this app with vs17 in the same machine printToPrinter method works fine .its only get stuck after publishing on iis.

i have tried

popt.PrinterName = printerSettings.PrinterName;
            rd.ReportClientDocument.PrintOutputController.PrintReport(popt);

this method too.
heres my actual code:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
        }

        ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
        rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reporting/Crystals/rptKitchenCopy.rpt")));


        rd.SetDataSource(dt);
        Response.Buffer = false;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();

        System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument pDoc = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();

        CrystalDecisions.Shared.PrintLayoutSettings PrintLayout = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.PrintLayoutSettings();

        System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings printerSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
        var dpn = settings.PrinterName;
        printerSettings.PrinterName = dpn;

        System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings pSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings(printerSettings);

        CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.PrintReportOptions popt = new CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.PrintReportOptions();
        popt.PrinterName = printerSettings.PrinterName;
        rd.ReportClientDocument.PrintOutputController.PrintReport(popt);



        // rd.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "\\ ";
       // rd.PrintToPrinter(printerSettings, pSettings, false, PrintLayout);
       // rd.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 1, 1);

        return File(stream, "application/pdf", "KitchenCopy.pdf");
```

i am expecting it to also print in iis server with its default printer that i have hosted in the same machine .

Comment: A local printer? Are you using a share name to define it?

Comment: yes its a local printer ,HP LaserJet 1100 Series, , method works fine when testing/debugging from visual studio, it does not work after publishing it, and if i comment out the printToPrinter line and only use File(stream, "application/pdf", "KitchenCopy.pdf"); line it works fine and it returns a pdf file.

Comment: you are not written that your development and hosted machine is same or not!  if both are differ than you need need to install a printer on hosted machine, still you have some issue then hosting on your local iis and then test. Suppose both are on same machine then ideally issue will not raised.

Comment: its in same machine, i have found what was causing the problem !! and added the answer . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what was causing this issue , as i hosted and developed my web app on windows 10 (both in same machine), the reason behind the problem was by default my windows 10 iis was detecting  'microsoft print to pdf' as a default printer , so i have turned off this from windows features and added

PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings(); 
rd.PrintOptions.PrinterName = settings.PrinterName;

in my code. hope it will someone with the same issue .Thanks